# ASP MVC 2 Pattern for implementing CanExecute style commands

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have come from WPF (MVVM) background and trying to shift to MVC 2. Is there any pattern in MVC2 where you can use Commanding/Command buttons like `<input>` which you use to submit the form so that you can hide/disable when you try to Render the View.

In MVVM world, your commands could implement ICommand interface, and it had CanExecute method which was quite useful. I was wondering if there is anything similar in ASP MVC 2 ?

The only way I can think of, is to do it in the View, so that I can check the flag on ViewModel (CanSave) and depending on that show/hide the `<input>` tag.

Basically I want to have 2 version of the website running, one in Read-Only mode and the other Editing mode.

Let me know if you need any clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC does not feature the notion of 'controls', as are found in classic ASP.NET and WPF. The foundational blocks of ASP.NET MVC are HTML elements, like `<input>`, `<button>` et cetera. Naturally, these don't offer the functionality you're looking for (i.e. Implementation of the ICommand Interface).

The scenario that you're looking at (i.e. two modes of your form) can be (and arguably *should be*) dealt with at the View level. You're already facing the right direction: have a 'CanSave' property on your Model, and use this in the View to determine what is generated.

Example:

```
<% if (Model.CanSave)
    { %>
        <p>First Name: <%= Html.TextBox("firstname", Model.firstname) %> </p>
<%  }
    else
    { %>
        <p>First Name: <%=Model.firstname %></p>
<%  } %>
```

You'll probably want to check out the *DisplayTemplates* and *EditorTemplates*... very handy for this scenario. Brad Wilson does a good job [here](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html).

It will help you move to this:

```
<%= (Model.CanSave) ? Html.EditorFor(x => x.firstname) : Html.DisplayFor(x => x.firstname) %>
```

...which makes your View clean and nice.

Comment: tnx. that' the directon I would like to head for

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get MVC to do this it's relatively worth it to hand-code something like this vb-style pseudocode. This involves...

#### Subclassing your controls.

Not as much of a pain as it sounds, but, it is a medium sized one. Therefore it is only appropriate for medium-sized to large apps. But worth it for them.

```
Interface BaseUIControl
    Property Enabled as Boolean
    Property Visible as Boolean
    Property Name as String
    Property EntireStateAsXML as string ' You can use this to do EVERYTHING!        

Interface UserActionItem
    Event Clicked(sender as UserActionItem ... don't pass anything from UI namespaces!)

Class MyButton (or link, etc.) Implement BaseUIControl, UserActionItem Inherits UI.Button
```

How does this help? You've basically replaced the missing functionality. Your Controller (or even application layer) can be aware of the UI components by interface only, so they won't have to see the UI types.

### more...

You can leverage this philosophy to control *everything*. This has saved me thousands of hours of monkey code.

```
Interface TextControl
    Property Value as text

Interface CheckControl 
    Property Checked as boolean
```

The above two are Pretty basic - you inherit MyCheckBox and MyTextBox from the UI versions and implement the appropriate.

Of course you could set up common code to loop thru all controls and auto-validate (or loop thru and get each one's XML to autobind the whole form).

```
Interface ValidationBase
    Property Required as Boolean
```

If you have a text or numeric-only mask or restricitons built into 2 subclasses...

```
Interface ValidationNumeric           
    Property MinVal, MaxVal as double 

Interface ValidationText
    Property MinLen, MaxLen as double
```

No, it won't go to the database for you. But this sweeps a ton of crud under the rug.

You can even set these property values in the UI designer - yes, putting BL in bed with UI, BUT, if you only have one UI for the BL, actually works very well.

Now image a UI with a mix of things like listbox/multiselect, double-list picker controls, checked listbox, a groupbox of option buttons/checkboxes ...

```
Interface Selector
    property Items as list (of string) 
    property SelectedItems as list (of string)
```

Use what works on the UI - your generic routines can care less what they look like!! The subclassed UI pieces will just implement them to set/get the right values.

In addition ... we added 'validationEquation', ActivatesEquation (gray/ungray), SetValueTriggerEquation (if true, set value to SetValueEquation, otherwise, leave alone), which allowed controls to be set to simple values from other items (basically getting the values from bound objects as if using reflection) via Pascal Gayane's [Expression Evaluator](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/eval3.aspx) (it reads .net types!)

You can also subclass the main form, have it recurse thru all it's subcontrols, put together the XML's for the whole screen, and serialize it like that. You can have your own classes implement these in the non-UI layers and use it to totally (de/)serialize the UI state, and use them to read the UI too, if they relate to a business object, to map to it.

It's *unbelievable* how much this simplifies a complex app. We have one with 1200+ data entry panels (... pages... ours is a thickclient app) that will fill out 250 different paper forms at 250K LOC. The form definitions contain the 'name' of each control and this is pulled from the XML generated from the screens. We probably saved 500K LOC as many of the screens have no code behind them or only trivial code; all the databinding, validation, etc. is handled by common routines that reference the interfaces.

Like I say, this only works for a big app. Spend at least 2-3 weeks developing 90% of the functionality, though; probably another month throughout the 2 years dev maturing it. I am guessing your apps is big if you're caring about ICommand and its conveniences. I would put the payback at 15-20 moderately complex pages.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you could write a `ControllerCommand` class to encapsulate this. Something like this:

```
public class ControllerCommand
{
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public object RouteValues { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

Your Details viewmodel might use it like this:

```
public class DetailsModel
{
    public guid Id { get; set;}
    // some other viewmodel properties
    public ControllerCommand Edit { get; set; }
}
```

You could write extension methods on `HtmlHelper` to replace the built-in ones:

```
public MvcHtmlString CommandLink(this HtmlHelper html, string linkText, ControllerCommand command, object htmlAttributes)
{
    if (command.IsEnabled)
    {
        return html.ActionLink(linkText, command.Action, command.Controller, command.RouteValues, htmlAttributes);
    }
    else
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(linkText);
        // perhaps return <span class="disabled-command">linkText</span>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways I have found is to use Filter attributes which you can put in your Actions, but that only handles CanExecute on the server side.

For the GUI side, couldnt find better way than putting If statements to check if the user is Priviliged to run particular action (i.e. Edit/Delete buttons)